# Error in checking if discord message contains item from a text file (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

so I'm trying to code a basic discord moderation bot for my server. What I'm attempting to do is have the bot check a message to see if it contains a word from a text file (in the same directory). Here is my code:

```
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from datetime import datetime


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  for word in bad_words:
    if message.content.contains(word):

      await message.delete()
      badwordEmbed = discord.Embed(title="You have sent a bad word!", description="", colour=0xff0000, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
      await message.channel.send(embed=badwordEmbed)


keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

However, when I send a discord message containing a word from the .txt file, I get this error:

```
   if message.content.contains(word):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

I have a feeling this is a basic error, but for now I'm not sure so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

It's `in` you need:

```
if word in message.content:
```

Strings have a `__contains__` method (note the underscores), but this is used by `in`.